# python urllib request with cookie processor and user-agent header

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Using python 3, I am making an http request that needs to handle cookies and represent itself as a browser. This is what I am trying.

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor)
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.open(uri)
```

I believe I have built an 'OpenDirector' here but have no idea how to get the reponse from it. It doesn't seem have a read method. How do I finish this?

```
content = opener.read.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
```

Above doesn't work because there is no read method.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor)
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
content =  opener.open(uri).read().decode('utf-8', errors='replace')
```